# pytorch cuda not available: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error

Tags: pytorch

I successfully ran pytorch, however after a system reboot I get the following error calling torch.cuda.is_available():

`UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1616554782469/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)`

Output of nvidia-smi:

```
nvidia-smi

Thu Jun 24 09:11:39 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.23.05    Driver Version: 455.23.05    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  On   | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    26W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Environment information:

```
python collect_env.py

Collecting environment information...
/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1616554782469/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
PyTorch version: 1.8.1
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.1
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (x86_64)
GCC version: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: glibc-2.28
Python version: 3.9 (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-4.19.0-17-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.28
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: Could not collect
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB
Nvidia driver version: 455.23.05
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.19.2
[pip3] torch==1.8.1
[pip3] torchaudio==0.8.0a0+e4e171a
[pip3] torchmetrics==0.3.2
[pip3] torchvision==0.9.1
[conda] _tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl    conda-forge
[conda] cudatoolkit               11.1.74              h6bb024c_0    nvidia
[conda] mkl                       2020.2                      256  
[conda] mkl-service               2.3.0            py39he8ac12f_0  
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py39h54f3939_0  
[conda] mkl_random                1.0.2            py39h63df603_0  
[conda] numpy                     1.19.2           py39h89c1606_0  
[conda] numpy-base                1.19.2           py39h2ae0177_0  
[conda] pytorch                   1.8.1           py3.9_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0    pytorch
[conda] tensorflow                2.4.1           mkl_py39h4683426_0  
[conda] tensorflow-base           2.4.1           mkl_py39h43e0292_0  
[conda] torchaudio                0.8.1                      py39    pytorch
[conda] torchmetrics              0.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
[conda] torchvision               0.9.1                py39_cu111    pytorch
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently ran into this error when migrating my gpu containers from nvidia docker to podman. The root cause for me was that /dev/nvidia-uvm* files were missing that CUDA apparently needs to work. Check that you have them:

```
# ls -ld /dev/nvidia*
drwxr-x--- 2 root root       80 Oct  6 21:11 /dev/nvidia-caps
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 254 Oct  6 21:08 /dev/nvidia-modeset
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 237,   0 Oct  6 21:13 /dev/nvidia-uvm       <-IMPORTANT
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 237,   1 Oct  6 21:13 /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools <-IMPORTANT
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195,   0 Oct  6 21:08 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 255 Oct  6 21:08 /dev/nvidiactl
```

`sudo nvidia-modprobe -c 0 -u` should load kernel modules and create these dev files if you don't see them. Or alternatively look for `/sbin/create-uvm-dev-node` script from ubuntu that they created to fix their issue with them.

If you use GPU inside a container/VM, these dev files also need to be present in the container. Normally nvidia runtime scripts will take care of passing them through. If that doesn't happen you could try passing some explicit `--device /dev/nvidia-uvm --device /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools` to docker/podman run.